# How do I use GET method with sending json data in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

API route in Python (Flask)

```py
@app.route('/secret')
def secret():
    if request.get_json(force=True)['key'] == 'secret key':
        return jsonify(msg='Hello!')
```

It is working linux terminal

```sh
curl -iX GET -d '{"key":"secret key"}' localhost
```

Linux terminal output this

```json
{"msg":"Hello!"}
```

It doesn't need to work in browser.

```java
try{
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                        new URL("http://<my local ip>/secret").openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();
    JSONObject jsonInput = new JSONObject();
    jsonInput.put("key", "secret key");
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    byte[] input = jsonInput.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String responseLine = null;
    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(responseLine.trim());
    }
    return response.toString();
} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Although the GET method is set to the connection request in my codes, a POST request is being sent to the Python server.

> [Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMMJO.png)

***Is it impossible to fix this?***

Comment: Is it possible to use HttpUrlConnection to do this?

Comment: I am sorry if I still wasn't able to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request Body` is not recommended in `HTTP GET` requests. See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

When you try to write on a `URL`, you are implicitly `POST`ing on it despite you had set `GET` as the HTTP method. At below lines:

```
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
byte[] input = jsonInput.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
os.write(input, 0, input.length);
```

For confirmation of my words see [Writing to a URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

> writing to a URL is often called posting to a URL. The server
> recognizes the POST request and reads the data sent from the client.